# [Ashot][Selenium] - Take screenshot for iOS and Android

Tags: selenium, testing, automation, automated-tests, ashot

I am currently trying to implement Ashot to take screenshots for my current project , it is working for desktop.

But I would like to know how to implement it for iOS and Android devices, there is not much information available on the internet.

I have used the following, viewport and it is taking screenshot for ipad:

Screenshot FullPage = new AShot().shootingStrategy(ShootingStrategies.viewportRetina(100, 0, 0, 2)).takeScreenshot(driver);

but I would like to know how to play around with the given properties to produce screenshots for other IOS and android devices.

Thanks,

Kiera

Answer (score 0):

Nothing difference))) except `dpr` just need to play a bit with this parameter, I guess :) And do not forget to read info here https://github.com/pazone/ashot/issues

Comment: I did play with the dpr but wasn't able to produce screenshots for other devices.

Comment: ok, so you take a screenshot from a real device connected to your PC or from cloud service like Browserstak? My successful experience is based on Browserstack

Comment: I'm currently searching for something free to use and take the screenshot using emulator